# How do I change vim cursor color

Tags: cursor, color

I use vim `version 8.0.707`.
My cursor blinks but make the character disappear half the time.
I'd like it to behave as usual: display the negative color.

How can I do that please?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only change GUI vim cursor color in vim:

```
augroup tune_colors | au!
    au ColorScheme * hi Cursor guibg=red guifg=white
augroup END
```

If you use terminal vim, change cursor colors in terminal settings.

Comment: I'm using terminal vim so I just applied your 2nd solution. Thanks